# Copy paste shape by using VBA in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to copy paste shape by using VBA in PowerPoint.
This code can't exit from `If...End If` statement.
What's wrong with my code?

```
Sub pasteshape()
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape
        For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes    
            If oSh.Fill.Type = msoFillSolid Then
               oSh.Duplicate
            End If
        Next
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by __ This code can't exit from If...End If statement__?  Perhaps you need and `Else` clause?

Comment: @ainwood the `Shapes` collection is being added to, every time a solid-fill shape is encountered. The loop is infinite as written.

Comment: Ah - good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're changing the collection you're iterating, *as you're iterating it*; that's *always* a bad idea!

So you have an infinite loop, because every time you duplicate a shape, you effectively add a solid-fill shape to the `oSl.Shapes` collection, which is then a solid-fill shape that should be duplicated - right?

You need a way to separate the process of *knowing which shapes to copy* and that of *copying solid-fill shapes*.

Make a new collection:

```
Dim solidShapes As Collection
Set solidShapes = New Collection
```

Now iterate the slides and their shapes, but instead of copying right away, *add them to that collection*:

```
    For Each currentShape In currentSlide.Shapes    
        If currentShape.Fill.Type = msoFillSolid Then
           solidShapes.Add currentShape
        End If
    Next
```

Notice I'm using *readable* identifiers without [*Systems Hungarian*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) (aka useless) prefixes (read that link! *Especially* if you're a firm believer of Hungarian Notation).

Now you can iterate the `solidShapes` collection, and `.Duplicate` every item in it.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!